# Hola, quisiera saber como puedo organizar los ciclos para que me imprima las notas y el promedio de los estudiantes

Tags: java

Diseñe un algoritmo y desarrolle un programa en Java que abra dos archivos, un archivo tiene los nombres de los estudiantes y el otro archivo las notas del semestre.  Para calcular la nota de cada estudiante se tienen 3 notas en el archivo de notas.

El algoritmo debe:

Garantizar la integridad de los archivos, es decir: contar primero la cantidad de estudiantes y luego contar que hayan las notas de acuerdo con la regla.

Ejemplo: Si en el archivo de estudiantes hay 5 estudiantes, el archivo de notas debe tener 15 notas.

Luego de garantizar que todo está bien, se procede a hacer los siguientes cálculos:

Imprimir el nombre de cada estudiante junto con su nota final. Las dos primeras notas valen 33% cada una y la tercera vale el 34%
Al final, imprimir cuántos estudiantes en total tiene el curso, cuántos perdieron(nota por debajo de 3), cuántos ganaron y la nota promedio del grupo.

```
import java.io.*;

public class estudiantes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File archivo = new File("C:\\Users\\Acer\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\Estudiantes.txt");
            FileReader archivo_lec = new FileReader(archivo);
            BufferedReader estudiantes = new BufferedReader(archivo_lec);

            File notas = new File("C:\\Users\\Acer\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\Notas.txt");
            FileReader notasle = new FileReader(notas);
            BufferedReader guardar = new BufferedReader(notasle);
        
            int cont1 = 0, cont = 0, cont2 = 0;
            String linea, linea2;
            linea = estudiantes.readLine();
            linea2 = guardar.readLine();

            double normal, normal2, promedio;

            //promedio = (nota1+nota2+nota3+nota4+nota5+nota6+nota7)/7;

            while(linea != null) {
                linea = estudiantes.readLine();
                cont1++;
                cont = cont1*3;

                while(linea2 != null) {
                    linea2 = guardar.readLine();
                    cont2++;
                }
            }

            if(cont == cont2) {
                while(cont2%2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(cont2);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Hay un error en los archivos");
            }

            guardar.close();
            estudiantes.close();
        } catch (Exception error) {
            System.out.println("Ocurrió un error: \n" + error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hasta el momento solo llevo eso, los calculos de las notas se como hacerlos y del promedio igual, pero como hago para que me imprima cada estudiante mas su nota al frente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que tendrías que hacer es contabilizar la cantidad de estudiantes y validar que la cantidad de notas sea 3 veces; si esto no ocurre no se halla el promedio.
Al leer los nombres de los estudiantes y las notas, lo almacenas en un `ArrayList`.
Te dejo el código funcional comentado

```
try {
            File archivo = new File("D:\\archivosJava\\Estudiantes.txt");
            FileReader archivo_lec = new FileReader(archivo);
            BufferedReader estudiantes = new BufferedReader(archivo_lec);

            File notas = new File("D:\\archivosJava\\Notas.txt");
            FileReader notasle = new FileReader(notas);
            BufferedReader guardar = new BufferedReader(notasle);

            int cont1=0, cont2=0;
            double nota;//Para usar el peso que tendrá cada nota
            double  suma,promedio;
            String linea; 
            ArrayList<String> listaEstudiantes= new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Double> listaNotas=new ArrayList<>();
            
            do{
                linea = estudiantes.readLine();
                if(linea!=null){
                    cont1++;//contamos cantidad de estudiantes
                    listaEstudiantes.add(linea);//añadimos estudiante al ArrayList
                }                
            }while(linea!=null);
            
            do{
                linea = guardar.readLine();
                if(linea!=null){
                    cont2++;//contamos cantidad de notas
                    //convertimos cada String a double
                    listaNotas.add(Double.parseDouble(linea));//añadimos nota al ArrayList
                }                
            }while(linea!=null);
            
            if(cont1*3==cont2){                
                System.out.println("La cantidad de notas es correcta de acuerdo al Nº estudiantes");  
                for(int i=0;i<listaEstudiantes.size();i++){
                    suma=0;
                    for(int j=i*3;j<i*3+3;j++){//cada for interno recorre 3 elementos de nota
                        //cada 3 notas el peso de la nota es 34%
                        if((j+1)%3==0)
                           nota= listaNotas.get(j)*34;
                        else
                            nota=listaNotas.get(j)*33;
                        
                        suma=suma+nota;
                    }
                    promedio=suma/100;//debido a que tienen peso 33,33 y 34
                    //Mostramos nombre de cada estudiante con su promedio
                    System.out.println("Alumno: "+listaEstudiantes.get(i));
                    System.out.println("Promedio: "+promedio);
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }else if(cont1*3>cont2)
                System.out.println("Hay menos notas");
            else if(cont1*3<cont2)
                System.out.println("Hay más notas");
        }catch (Exception error) {
            System.out.println("Ocurrió un error: \n" + error);
        }
```